# tkinter: mouse lag on links

Tags: python, tkinter

Writing an application in python/Tkinter, I sometimes have a page with a number of hyperlinks
(defined by the class HyperlinkManager, in http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-text-hyperlink.htm).

I noticed that if a large number of links is present, the mouse develops a bit of lag when hovering on the links.
Do you know if this is typical in Tkinter apps, or if there are countermeasures?

alessandro

Comment: The lag disappears if I comment the _enter/_leave methods, so they are certainly the culprits...
`def _enter(self, event):
        self.text.config(cursor="hand2")

def _leave(self, event):
        self.text.config(cursor="")`

Comment: +1: self-answers are good for stackoverflow. Tkinter is a wrapper around tk and the tk text-widget is relatively sub-optimal in its enter/leave bindings. Depending on your needs, you may find something like a canvas more performant or even PyGTK. Tk was pretty nifty a decade ago but is beginning to show its age.

Comment: @msw: Why do you say the text widget is sub-optimal in its enter and leave bindings? I'm able to create a text widget with 1000 unique tags, each with unique bindings for enter and leave, and it works flawlessly (though it's a bit slow to create all those tags).

Comment: how do you define mouse lag? Does the cursor slow down (ie: you move the mouse fast but the cursor moves slow), or that when you move over a ling it takes a perceptible amount of time for the cursor to change to a hand, or something else entirely?

Comment: don't let the "beginning to show it's age" comment scare you. Tkinter has aged pretty well and is still a very viable choice for a very wide range of problems. It's not useful to build the next GIMP or Eclipse, but for the majority of everyday GUIs it's quite capable. This is especially true starting with python 2.7 and the inclusion of themed (ttk) widgets. And if you're doing something with text, arguably no other toolkit can compete with Tkinter's text widget for ease of use and power.

Answer (score 1):

There is no particular slowness in Tkinter's handling of tag enter and leave bindings for a reasonable number of tags that I'm aware of, though there may be inefficiencies in the implementation of the HyperlinkManager class. And certainly, what you do with those enter/leave events can introduce some lag. Since entering and leaving can happen very rapidly, if the code is slow it will introduce some lag.

Is it possible for you to give a small example program that shows this lag that you're seeing?